# Can't insert spaces for code block, get a newline instead

Tags: bug, editor, google-chrome

So I came across the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944605/how-to-access-and-write-the-resource-file-from-local-c-path-in-server-c-sharp):

> I have XML file that store string which located in local c inside server and I want every different project to access and read the XML file. At the same time every user may edit the XML file anytime which all of the user have the same string.
>
> I use .resx in class library to embed the XML but the XML file only copies into the class library. When I make changes to XML file in local C it will not update.
>
> XDocument.Load(typeof(ResourceFile.Resource1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("C:/File.xml"));
>
> I use above code to read my XML file.

And I wanted to fix it so that it looked like this:

> I have XML file that store string which located in local c inside server and I want every different project to access and read the XML file. At the same time every user may edit the XML file anytime which all of the user have the same string.
>
> I use .resx in class library to embed the XML but the XML file only copies into the class library. When I make changes to XML file in local C it will not update.
>
> ```
> XDocument.Load(typeof(ResourceFile.Resource1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("C:/File.xml"));
> ```
>
> I use above code to read my XML file.

But placing my cursor before `XDocument` and pressing space results in new lines, not spaces. The only way to fix it was to create a new line above, insert 4 spaces, and then delete the existing newline.

Since there has been a little disbelief, here is what I saw in the editor (the newlines above the code were inserted by pressing the space bar only) versus what I saw rendered:

> [image: editor]

Rendered:

> [image: rendered]

My browser: `Google Chrome  75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)`

I've tested in `Firefox Quantum 67.0.4 (64-bit)` and `Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0`, and I can't reproduce the issue, so it seems to be a Chrome-specific issue.

I'm assuming this is a bug with adding text/spaces before a long unbroken line.

Comment: That's a Chrome bug: [reprex](https://jsfiddle.net/pLqu7moa/) & [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713969&q=textarea%20new%20line&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @Kaiido has indicated that it's a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713969&q=textarea%20new%20line&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't inserting newlines.  That's just how the text wrapping works.  You can type the spaces, and you'll see the change in the preview.  Once you get to four you'll see the code indent.

Comment: Try it. That's not the case.

Comment: I did, and it worked as intended for me (I'm using FireFox).  What's your browser?

Comment: Chrome version 75.0.3770.100.

Comment: I can confirm that I don't see the issue in the latest version of Firefox. It works as expected, and as you describe. It seems to be an issue that only presents in Chrome.